# Using GET/POST method in shopping cart using two databases

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django-views, django-templates

I'm creating an e-commerce site using django, the product data is divided into 2 databases `product(products)` and `size(product size)`, but I can't make it send the data from the size database to the shopping cart, it runs the program well only if it uses the product database.

> To try to add the size bank I added the lines `var _sizeId=$(".size-id-"+_index).val();` `'id':_sizeId,` in the javascript file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Add to cart
$(document).on('click',".add-to-cart",function(){
var _vm=$(this);
var _index=_vm.attr('data-index');
var _qty=$(".product-qty-"+_index).val();
var _productId=$(".product-id-"+_index).val();
var _sizeId=$(".size-id-"+_index).val();
var _productImage=$(".product-image-"+_index).val();
var _productTitle=$(".product-title-"+_index).val();
var _productPrice=$(".product-price-"+_index).val();
var _sizeSize=$(".product-size-"+_index).val();
// ajax
$.ajax({
url:'/add-to-cart',
date:{
'id':_productId,
'id':_sizeId,
'image':_productImage,
'qty':_qty,
'title':_productTitle,
'price':_productPrice,
'size':_sizeSize,
},
dataType:'json',
beforeSend:function(){
_vm.attr('disabled',true);
},
success:function(res){
$(".cart-list").text(res.totalitems);
_vm.attr('disabled',false);
}
});
// End
});
// End

});
```

> In the view.py file structure I added  `'size': request.GET['size'],`

```
def add_to_cart(request):
# del request.session['cartdata']
cart_p = {}
    # when requesting the id requested that it get specific data from the id you selected
    #like image,title,qty and price
cart_p[str(request.GET['id'])] ={
'image': request.GET['image'],
        'title': request.GET['title'],
'qty': request.GET['qty'],
'price': request.GET['price'],
        'size': request.GET['size'],
}
if 'carddata' in request.session:
            #if the request is a valid id, it will call the cartdata variable
if str(request.GET['id']) in request.session['cartdata']:
cart_data = request.session['cartdata']
cart_data[str(request.GET['id'])]['qty'] = int(
cart_p[str(request.GET['id'])]['qty'])
cart_data.update(cart_data)
request.session['cartdata'] = cart_data
else:
cart_data = request.session['cartdata']
cart_data.update(cart_p)
request.session['cartdata'] = cart_data
else:
request.session['cartdata'] = cart_p
return JsonResponse({'data': request.session['cartdata'], 'totalitems': len(request.session['cartdata'])})
```

In the html file it is like this when selecting the button he would have to send the data to the cart.

```
                  <div class="input-group my-3" style="width:48%;">
                     <input type="number" value="1" class="form-control product-qty-{{product.id}}" class="form-control product-qty-{{size.id}}" id= "productQty" />
                     <div class="input-group-append">
                        <input type="hidden" class="product-id-{{product.id}}" value="{{product.id}}" />
                        <input type="hidden" class="size-id-{{size.id}}" value="{{size.id}}" />
                        <input type="hidden" class="product-image-{{product.id}}" value="{{product.image}}" />
                        <input type="hidden" class="product-title-{{product.id}}" value="{{product.title}}" />
                        <input type="hidden" class="product-size-{{size.id}}" value="{{size.size}}" />
                        <input type="hidden" class="product-price-{{product.id}}" value="{{product.price}}" />
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark add-to-cart" data-index="{{product.id}}" data-index="{{size.id}}" type="button" id= "addToCartBtn"><i class="icon-line-shopping-cart"></i>Add Bag</button>
                     </div>
                  </div>
```

But it returns only finding the data from the product database.

Comment: I don't think the python script is readable, please spend sometime to correct the indents and make it more readable.